# Cash register slide up/slide down effect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate

I am trying to create a `slideUp`, `slideDown` effect with a `div`. Basically the `div` contains the contents of a cart. When the user is looking at items the cart should be tucked away but when they tap on an `img` it should pop up and toggle. It looks like this ...

[image]

I have got all sorts of crazy effects and most just about always completely hide the cart when it is toggled. It should just return to the position shown in the image above.

My code at the moment.

```
 $( ".cart" ).on( "click", function() {

   if ($('.tabBox').height() > 91)
       {  
       $('.tabBox').height('90px').slideUp();
       console.log('slide up');
       }
   else
       {
       $('.tabBox').height('150px').slideDown();
       console.log('slide Down');
       }
  });
```

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avoLyP) (no images) If you click on an item the cart will popup. You will notice also the cart does not slide up but pops up. I would like it to slide up and slide down gracefully But return to it's original position (not off the screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the **animate** function instead. Also, I'm not quite sure if I got this correct, but it looks like the cart has 3 possible states:

- hidden: nicely tucked away, untill somebody clicks an image
- minimized: just visible, but only the cart, clicking the cart => maximize
- maximized: completely visible, cart + order(?), clicking the
  cart => minimize

I'd simply remove the first state, which makes the solution a bit easier, but as you can see, adjusting to accomodate for this 3rd state will not be that hard:

```
cartMaximized = false;

$( ".cart" ).on( "click", function() {

    $('.tabBox').stop( true );

    if( cartMaximized ) {
       $('.tabBox').animate({ height: '90px' });
    }
    else
    {
       // You can play around with outerHeight() and so on, but that's out of scope
       // $('.tabBox').animate({ height: $('.content').outerHeight()+45+'px' });
       $('.tabBox').animate({ height: '150px' });
    }

    cartMaximized = !cartMaximized;
});
```

--- tested and working

But this might be "brittle" due to resizing and so on, but I bet you can figure something out :-)